# how to publish to user timeline after recent facebook api changes?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

We have been using publish_actions permission with facebook javascript api to post to user timeline from the app. The feature stopped working and when i logged in to developers.facebook.com then there were few alerts saying that some changes were made recently. Upon further investigation, i found that publish_actions has been removed.

So i am wondering what is the replacement of publish_actions or how does one go about using post to user timeline after the recent facebook api change? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

> Developers currently utilizing publish_actions are encouraged to switch to Facebook's Share dialogs for web, iOS and Android.